# Почему форма не отправляется?

Tags: php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">

    <title>Отправка формы на почту </title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <style>
        form {
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <form action="mail.php" method="POST">
                <legend>Заголовок формы</legend>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Введите ваше имя</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="user_name" placeholder="Например, Иван">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Введите номер телефона</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="user_phone" placeholder="+7 (999) 99 99 999">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Введите email</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="user_email" placeholder="mail@mail.ru">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Отправить форму</button>
            </form>
        </div><!-- .col-sm-4 -->
      </div> <!-- .row -->

    </div><!-- /.container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

<?php

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
$email = $_POST['user_email'];

$mail->isSMTP();

$mail->Host = 'smtp.yandex.ru';
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->Username = 'mrkrojlik@yandex.ru';
$mail->Password = '';

$mail->addAddress('mrkrojlik@yandex.ru');

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

$mail->Subject = 'Заявка с тестового сайта';
$mail->Body    = '' .$name . ' оставил заявку, его телефон ' .$phone. '<br>Почта этого пользователя: ' .$email;
$mail->AltBody = '';

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

 $mail->setFrom('mrkrojlik@yandex.ru', 'Сайт site.ru');

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    header('location: thank-you.html');
}
?>
```

Ошибка: 2020-01-11 00:45:05 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 2020-01-11 00:45:05 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Необходимо уточнить причину ошибки. Попробуйте $mail->ErrorInfo, чтобы вывести ошибку, вместо echo 'Error'; Тогда станет более понятно.

Comment: просто белый экран, нет никакой ошибки

Comment: Вы так написали     echo 'Error' . $mail->ErrorInfo;? Проверил у себя - отображение ошибки выводится.

Comment: и что означает эта ошибка?)

Comment: ну так Вы напишите ту ошибку, которую у Вас выдаёт система.  Угадывать никто не будет. У меня пишет, что не указан отправитель.

Comment: Почта - яндекса, а сервер куда пытаетесь подключиться - гугла. Меняйте на ssl://smtp.yandex.ru

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Чтобы использовать SMTP гугла, надо либо завести приложение и авторизовать его в аккаунте, либо разрешить подключение неавторизованным приложениям.

- Авторизуйтесь в своём аккаунте.
- Перейдите https://myaccount.google.com/u/2/lesssecureapps
- Включите доступ для неавторизованных приложений

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Протестируйте подключение повторно.

Поскольку вы используете phpmailer я рекомендую включить настройку:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

На стадии разработки вы будете видеть абсолютно все этапы подключения и ответы и столкнувшись с очередной ошибкой вы либо дополните свою проблему тут, либо сможете нагуглить решение.

Насколько я вижу - у вас не указан отправитель.

```
    $mail->setFrom('berestovayamaria@gmail.com', 'Сайт site.ru');
```

Обратите внимание, что если вы хотите отправлять сообщения не себе, а допустим, клиентам, то велика вероятность попадания сообщений в спам используемым вами способом.

Это лечится заведением корпоративной почты, например на mail.ru или яндекс, подтверждением прав на домен и внесением всех необходимых mx и txt записей в DNS домена.

Дальше пользуетесь этой почтой через SMTP для рассылки.